# How to find theoretical bound for inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let take $n$ and $B$ to be integers 
Such that $B$ is even.
 my question is how to find the  smallest value  of $n_{0} $ in which 
 When $n>n_{0}$ the following inequality is hold

$$ n!>B(B+2) $$

Comment: Also $n_0=B+1$ works.

Comment: I try to use the inverse of gamma function but there is no complete formula for it

Comment: The issue is that if you're looking for *an* $n_0$, the above one works among many other obvious choices; but if you're looking for the smallest $n_0$, the inverse Gamma function is the only option. So it's unclear what you want exactly.

Comment: Yes i want the smallest $n_{0}$